# SQLiteConstraintException is being thrown each time while adding dynamic datas to a table

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a table and adding elements to table as follows,

`

```
public void addPendingOrders(PendingOrdersDao pendingOrders) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_ID, pendingOrders.getId());
        values.put(KEY_SHIPMENT_NO, pendingOrders.getSipmentNo());
        values.put(KEY_SHIPMENT_REF_NO, pendingOrders.getShipmentRefNo());
        values.put(KEY_PRO_INV_NO, pendingOrders.getProformoInvoiceNumber());
        values.put(KEY_PRO_INV_DATE, pendingOrders.getProformoInvoiceDate());
        values.put(KEY_SHIPMENT_DATE, pendingOrders.getShipmentDate());
        values.put(KEY_PT_OF_CONTACT, pendingOrders.getPointOfContact());
        values.put(KEY_PRODUCT, pendingOrders.getProduct());
        values.put(KEY_QTY, pendingOrders.getQuantity());
        values.put(KEY_RATE, pendingOrders.get_rate());
        values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, pendingOrders.getAmount());
        values.put(KEY_PRODUCT_IMG, pendingOrders.getProductImage());
        values.put(KEY_SHIPMENT_STAT, pendingOrders.getShipmentStatus());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_PENDINGORDERS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Then in my code, Im using the following code to add values to the table

```
for (PendingOrdersDao cn : allPendingOrders) {
                                        //int _id, String _shipmentNo, String _shipmentRefNo, String _proformoInvoiceNumber, String _proformoInvoiceDate, String _shipmentDate, String _pointOfContact, String _product, String _quantity, String _rate, String _amount, String _productImage, String _shipmentStatus) {



myitems.add(new PendingOrdersDao(cn.getId(), cn.getSipmentNo(), cn.getShipmentRefNo(), cn.getProformoInvoiceNumber(), cn.getProformoInvoiceDate(), cn.getShipmentDate(), cn.getPointOfContact(), cn.getProduct(), cn.getQuantity(), cn.get_rate(), cn.getAmount(), cn.getProductImage(), cn.getShipmentStatus()));

                                }
```

Each time when a view is clicked, the values will be retrieved using volley and those values will be stored in database. First time when the view is clicked, the datas are added to the database without any issues. Next time if Im  clicking the view, the new values are getting retrieved once again but the SQLiteConstraintException error is being thrown when newly fetched datas are being added to the table. I guess its because the id's of old values in the table  and new values  that are being inserted to the table are all same. Is there any ways through which I can handle this error? How can I clear the records in a table and insert newly fetched datas without getting sqlite constraint exception?

Error Log

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column id is not
>   unique (code 19)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
>   Method)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:973)
>                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)

This is the query that I use to create table

```
String CREATE_PENDING_ORDERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PENDINGORDERS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_SHIPMENT_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_SHIPMENT_REF_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_PRO_INV_NO + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_PRO_INV_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_SHIPMENT_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_PT_OF_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_PRODUCT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_QTY + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_RATE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_PRODUCT_IMG + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_SHIPMENT_STAT + " TEXT NOT NULL"
            + ")";
```

Comment: please show Your stacktrace..

Comment: i have posted the error log

Comment: First time, the values are being inserted correctly but by the second time, the values with same id are being inserted once again because I want  my app to show freshly fetched data  . This causes the problem.How can I handle this?

Comment: so please post Your sqlite string where You create Your database table...

Comment: you can't insert 2 values with the same id !!! that's why this error is generated

Comment: i want to clear previous record and insert new records each time when a button is clicked

Comment: or else is there any other way available to handle this error?

Comment: You have made Your key_id primary, if You do this, You can´t add two similar id´s. Is it important to add allways the same id? If not, use PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT and do not add the key. Then the key will be generated automatically...

Comment: if I use PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, duplication of data might happen. so same data might be displayed more than once in the ui. Because Im fetching all datas from a table and displaying it

Comment: I have solved it. Please read my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself. Following is the way that I should follow to insert datas dynamically,

```
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_PENDINGORDERS, null,
                values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

what `CONFLICT_REPLACE` does is that, each time when there is a conflict in in key that's defined as primary key, then it just replace the entire row with new record. You can also use `CONFLICT_IGNORE`, if you want to tell your app to ignore such errors.,